# onCreateView Changes are not Updated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-view

I have a `FragmentTabHost` with multiple tabs. I want to change the text inside some buttons inside one of the tabs, each time the user selects the tab, but I can't make it work. It looks like Android is caching the `fragment` even thoug `onCreateView` is being called.

Inside `onCreateView` I do (as a test):

```
static private int i = 0; // this is declared outside the onCreateView method
......
i++;
RadioButton button = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

I have loaded 6 tabs with this same fragment class, every time I select a tab for the first time, the button text gets the incremented value of `i`....but if I select any of these tabs another time, the text remains the same, just as it was in the first time I selected it. I know `i` is changing because I can select tabs multiple times (lets say I switch between tab 1 and 2 multiple times, every time I do it `onCreateView` is called and ´i´ is incremented), just to increment `i` and then select another tab for the first time (suppose it's tab 6), and the value of `i` being displayed as it should inside the button inside that fragment, but again, after that, the button's text isn't updating anymore.

This is important to me, because I have some strings that are translated to other languages and I can't trigger any updates in the button's language text.

How can I force Android to update the button's text?

---

EDIT:

I can accomplish this moving the updates inside `onResume`, but I would like to usnderstad what is happening inside `onCreateView` that things just don't get updated.

---

EDIT 2:

This is my `onCreateView` code:

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_tab, container, false);

........ // configuring some buttons and grids callbacks and animations

i++;
RadioButton button1 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setText(String.valueOf(i));

RadioButton button2 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setText(String.valueOf(i));

RadioButton button3 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
button3.setText(String.valueOf(i));

RadioButton button4 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
button4.setText(String.valueOf(i));


return rootView;
```

}

Comment: I think you might be trying to change the information on past views. I would have to see some more code.

Comment: Try using Log.d, to print the i Value when the fragment is created in the onCreate() method or onCreateView()

Comment: @Akagami which code part will help you to see it? My code is really straight forward in this...

Comment: @user3586222 I assure you i is changing it's just not being shown

Answer (score 0):

That is because the OncreateView(), is executed just one time, the operation executing everytime when you select a tab is the onResume();

Try moving your code to onResume() method.

```
public void onResume(){
      i++;
      RadioButton button = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
      button.setText(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, as I said, `i++` is running, which means that `onCreateView` is running, besides I can place a breakpoint in there and I can see that `onCreateView` is running.